# Why return 0 will never be executed inside this code?

Tags: ios, swift

I was using if and else if to determine the right Height for two different screen size and I get a warning on "return 0" saying that it will never be executed. How do I silent this warning?

is it possible to use case? x

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if UIScreen.main.sizeType == .iPhone4 || UIScreen.main.sizeType == .iPhone5 {
        return 213
    } else if UIScreen.main.sizeType == .iPhone6 {
        return 249
    } else {
        return 276
    }

    return 0
}
```

Comment: Delete the unneeded `return 0` line and the warning will be gone.

Comment: thank you, I was thinking of that but wasn't sure if it would be the right thing to do

Comment: Unrelated to your question but you should not be checking device type. Base your calculation on the current view size, not device type.

Comment: So what would be the correct way

Answer (score 2):

Your code MUST take one of the three branches in the if/else if/else block, and all three branches return, so execution can NEVER reach past this block. The compiler is smart enough to notice this (dead code removal optimization) and gives you a warning. Probably the simplest way is to either:

- leave out the return 0 line
- Change your code so that the else branch isn't an else any more:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if UIScreen.main.sizeType == .iPhone4 || UIScreen.main.sizeType == .iPhone5 {
        return 213
    } else if UIScreen.main.sizeType == .iPhone6 {
        return 249
    }
    return 276

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the "return 0" line from your code as compiler will never reach to this line ever.
And it is giving you warning because the IDE/compilers are able to point out these kind of mistakes
For example it will also give you a warning in the below example

```
int someVariable = 1;
if(someVariable ==null){ //It will also give a warning here as well as  someVariable can never be null 

}
```

So in short you can simply modify your code to

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if UIScreen.main.sizeType == .iPhone4 || UIScreen.main.sizeType == .iPhone5 {
        return 213
    } else if UIScreen.main.sizeType == .iPhone6 {
        return 249
    } else {
        return 276
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a `return` in the `if` branch, there is no need for the `else` keyword. The code will be executed correctly anyway.

As a refactoring it is usually called: remove the redundant else.

So it can be rewritten as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if UIScreen.main.sizeType == .iPhone4 || UIScreen.main.sizeType == .iPhone5 {
        return 213;
    }
    // else
    if UIScreen.main.sizeType == .iPhone6 {
        return 249;
    }
    // else
    return 276;
    // return 0;
}
```

As can be seen at the last comment, the line above it returns 276, so `return 0` is never called.